# How to show active state on hover/focus in two elements at the same time in Vue.js/Vuex

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vuex, vuex-orm

This is a **Vue.js** and **Vuex** related problem.

I'm building an aplication where I show a list of residences (ul -> li -> a) while at the same time showing those illustrations' position in an illustration, solved via SVG (active elements are path and polygon). If it was just the one element I could do show active state using only css, but because there are two active elements at the same time I need an event.

Previously I solved the issue by giving the residence, stored in Vuex, a **hasFocus: false** value, which I would change to **true** on mouseenter/focus and back to false on mouseout/focusout. With that I can add/remove a class **has-focus** to which I add the active state css. I have now redone the datastore to use **Vuex ORM**, after which I'm seeing worse frame rate drops when carying out the mutation.

Is there a better way of doing this than using a value in a Vuex (ORM) object model?

### Some code:

#### In Vuex:

```
residences: [
{
  id: 1,
  hasFocus: false,
  […] // Other values, not relevant to this question
},
{
  id: 2,
  hasFocus: false
},
…
…
],
```

#### In ResidenceItem.vue:

```
<router-link
  […]
  v-bind:class="{
    'has-focus': residence.hasFocus === true,
  }"
  @mouseenter.native.stop="toggleFocus(true)"
  @mouseout.native.stop="toggleFocus(false)"
  @focus.native.stop="toggleFocus(true)"
  @focusout.native.stop="toggleFocus(false)"
  […]
>
// Content
</router-link>
[…]

props: {
  id: {
    required: true,
  },
},


methods: {
  toggleFocus(focus) {
    Residence.update({
      where: this.id,
      data: {
        hasFocus: focus,
      },
    });
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

why should "hasFocus" be stored in vuex? is there a need to be?
if not, you should move it to `ResidenceItem.vue`'s `data()`.
i think it is a just temporary state on vue.

```
<router-link
  :class="{
    'has-focus': focused,
  }"
  @mouseenter.native.stop="focused = true"
  @mouseout.native.stop="focused = false"
  @focus.native.stop="focused = true"
  @focusout.native.stop="focused = false"
  […]
>
...

data() {
  return {
    focused: false,
  };
},
...
```

---

if hasFocus is needed in vuex (which i think it is a bad idea), you should use normal vuex state to store like `focusedResidenceId: null`.

I can provide more detail explanation if you need. Please let me know if you so.

Comment: I found a solution using eventbus instead of using hasFocus. The reason I needed something other than local data is because I have multiple components that need to react to the event. As you point out, this doesn't belong in vuex (orm) as it is event data. Eventbus solved the issue for me, although I see that I will have to migrate away from eventbus to something like [Mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt) in Vue.js v3.